# Get data from class/id in HTML and preview in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to convert WordPress post into custom layout (get only title and content) I want to implement this into my android application

Like entering post's url > get only title and content > Implement it in custom layout

I have tried using RSS but it's can't get anything in post

---

ID of title is `upside-post-title`

ID of content is `upside-single-content`

Content and Image are kept together in `upside-single-content` no individual id set by theme

**This is my post on website**

[image: WordPress Post]

**The result I want**

[image: Result]

I'm sorry if this question have been asked before I don't know the keyword I should use to search this type of things I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use Wordpress data (from your web page) in android applications, what about use REST API. There are some plugins that you could try, for example - https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/?

Then you could retrieve data that you want, and I'm pretty sure, that Title, Text and Image of a post will be fine with this.